# Update with JOIN from another table and get the most recent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `user` table with a one-to-many relationship to a `log` table.

Essentially, every time a user record is updated, a record is inserted into the log table.

Right now what I’d like to do is update the user table with the most recent log entry, setting their current status and notes fields to the most recently logged.

> **log** 
> id
> user_id
>  status
>  notes
>  datetime
>
> **user**
>       id
>       status
>       notes

The following Query almost works except it gets the first entry in the log table.

```
UPDATE user u 
INNER JOIN log l 
ON u.user_id = l.user_id
SET u.`status` = l.`status`, u.notes = l.notes
```

I would like it get the most recent, either based on the `datetime` field or simply the max `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the MAX(id) in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement like so:

```
UPDATE 
    u 
SET 
    u.status = l.status, 
    u.notes = l.notes
FROM 
   user u
   INNER JOIN log l ON u.user_id = l.user_id
WHERE 
   l.id = (
       SELECT
           MAX(id)
       FROM 
           log
       WHERE
           user_id = u.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually find the last record.  A good way to do this is with `not exists`:

```
UPDATE user u INNER JOIN
       log l 
       ON u.user_id = l.user_id
    SET u.`status` = l.`status`, u.notes = l.notes
    WHERE not exists (select 1
                      from log l2
                      where l2.user_id = l.user_id and
                            l2.datetime > l.datetime
                     );
```

This will work best with an index on `log(user_id, datetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE user u INNER JOIN log l INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(id) Last_id FROM log GROUP BY user_id) u on u.Last_id=l.id
on l.user_id=u.user_id
SET u.`status` = l.`status`, u.notes = l.notes
```

Hope this help.